# “TypeError: `level` is not a function” when using LevelJS 8.0.0

Tags: javascript, node.js, database, leveldb

Currently, I am testing LevelDB as a key–value store for my Node.js projects, but I am having this issue: when I import Level and run the sample code from the website, [leveljs.org](https://leveljs.org), I get this error:

```
TypeError: level is not a function
    at Object.<anonymous> (/home/runner/level/index.js:2:12)
    at Module._compile (node:internal/modules/cjs/loader:1155:14)
```

I have searched for this error and nothing has came up. I have tried importing `Level` in different ways and none of them have worked. Here is my code, which is identical to the sample code on the website:

```js
const level = require('level')
const db = level('./db', { valueEncoding: 'json' })

db.put('key', { example: true }, function (err) {
  if (err) throw err

  db.get('key', function (err, value) {
    if (err) throw err
    console.log(value)
  })
})
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When in doubt, always check the documentation at [GitHub](//github.com/Level/level#usage):

> ```js
> const { Level } = require('level')
>
> // Create a database
> const db = new Level('example', { valueEncoding: 'json' })
> ```

The README also has this note:

> If you are upgrading: please see [UPGRADING.md](//github.com/Level/level/blob/master/UPGRADING.md).

Version 8.0.0 (released 2022-03-25) states:

> ### Changes to initialization
>
> We started using classes, which means using `new` is now required. If you previously did:
>
> ```js
> const level = require('level')
> const db = level('db')
> ```
>
> You must now do:
>
> ```js
> const { Level } = require('level')
> const db = new Level('db')
> ```

It also notes:

> This release replaces `leveldown` and `level-js` with [`classic-level`](//github.com/Level/classic-level) and [`browser-level`](//github.com/Level/browser-level).

The [changelog](//github.com/Level/level/blob/master/CHANGELOG.md#800---2022-03-25) lists this as a breaking change:

> Breaking: switch to classic-level and browser-level ([#215](//github.com/Level/level/issues/215)) ([`ad22b21`](//github.com/Level/level/commit/ad22b21)) (Vincent Weevers).

The [website](//leveljs.org) is outdated (as of [2022-12-22, 22:09:03 UTC](//web.archive.org/web/20221222220903/https://leveljs.org)), and below the code sample it says:

> As of `level@5`, the above code works in Node.js, Electron and browsers!

But you’re almost certainly using 8.0.0, not 5.0.0.

Shortly after [bringing it up](https://github.com/Level/leveljs.org/issues/62) on the repository for leveljs.org, they fixed it.

Comment: Wow. This works. Thank you. I did not fully read the documentation, my mistake, thank you for helping.